# Implementation of a stack using a linked list C

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list, stack

I am asked to implement a stack using a linked list. The program declares two "stacks" and uses them in order to sort some integers stored inside a file. I have the following program that crashed at the beginning. I think the it crashes in the first while of the else.  (for the file, the user enters its name)

```
        /************************************************************************************************************************

    Input File: A text file named: "Numbers.txt" that contains integers in random order. These integers are seperated
                by either a space or a new line. This file is very essencial for the program to work, because from it the
                program gets the integers. below is an example of the file format: (Note that there is a new line after 
                the last integer in order for the file to be read correctly). 

                2  1  3  5  4  
                7  6  8  9

    Output File: None
    Description: This program reads integers in random order. These integers are sorted by the end of the program's execution. 
                 The sorting operations, using Push and Pop functions are managed by two structures of type stack_t. 
                 The first structure is the main one that will be shown to the user, the second one is the one that holds the
                 unsorted integers while sorting. By the end stack2 will be empty and stack 1 will be sorted. 
    *************************************************************************************************************************/
    #include <stdio.h>
    #define MAXSTACK 10 // Defining the size of the stack as being 10 elements

    typedef struct node s_Node;
    struct node {
        int element;
        s_Node*next;
    }; // Define the node_t structure with the element of the node and the pointer to the next node

    typedef struct{
        s_Node *top_stack;
    }stack_t; // Define the stack_t structure with a pointer to s_Node (the first element of the linked list)

    /*-------------------------- NEEDED PROTOTYPES --------------------------*/ 
    // Initializes a new stack and returns it
    stack_t NewStack();
    // Returns 1 if the stack is empty, 0 otherwise
    int Empty(stack_t q);
    // Returns 1 if the stack is full, 0 otherwise
    int Full(stack_t q);
    // Pushes the element e in the stack. Returns 1 if it could Push.
    int Push(int e, stack_t *q);
    // Pops an element, placing it in e. Returns 1 if it could Pop.
    int Pop(int *e, stack_t *q);
    // Search for the top element in the stack and returns it.
    int Peek (stack_t s);
    // Displays the content of the stack.
    void Printstack(const stack_t );

    /*============================ MAIN PROGRAM ============================*/
    main () {

        char filename [20];
        int newint, val1, val2;
        FILE *file;

        stack_t stack1;
        stack_t stack2; 
        stack1=NewStack(); //Initializing the stack
        stack2=NewStack();

        printf ("\n\tPlease Enter the name of the file that contains your integers: ");
        scanf ("%s", &filename);
        file = fopen (filename, "r");

    if (file!=NULL) {
    fscanf (file, "%d", &newint);   
     while (!feof (file)&&!Full (stack1))
     {


        if ( Empty (stack1)) // Putting the first integer read from the file into the first stack.
        {
            Push (newint, &stack1);     
        }   
        else if (newint <= Peek(stack1)) //If the integer read from the file is less or equal to the integer in the top of the stack
        { 
                Push(newint, &stack1); // Push the integer into stack1. 

        }
        else 
        {
            while ( newint > Peek (stack1) )
            {    //Repeat poping from stack1 and pushing into stack2
                // until it the integer read from the file is bigger than the top element of stack1
                printf ("gOT into THE WHILE LOOP\n");   
                Pop (&val1,&stack1);
                Push (val1, &stack2); 
                Printstack (stack2);            
            } 
            printf ("gOT OUT OF THE WHILE LOOP\n"); 
             Push (newint, &stack1); //Pushing the integer read from the file into the first stack.
             Printstack (stack1);
             while (!Empty(stack2))
             { // Keep poping elements from stack2 and pushing them into stack1 until stack2 is empty
                Pop (&val2,&stack2);
                Push (val2, &stack1);

             } 

        }
        fscanf (file, "%d", &newint); 
       } // End while

        if (feof(file)) printf ("\n\tYou have reached the end of the file: %s.\n\tThere are no more elements to read.",filename);
        else    printf ("\n\n\tYour stack is full.\n\tYou can not enstack more elemeents"); 
         fclose (file);
        printf ("\nThe final result");
        Printstack (stack1);
    }else printf ("Error!!! Your file did not open successefully!\n"); // Error checking in reading the file
    } // End main
    /*-------------------------- FUNCTION DEFINITIONS --------------------------*/
        // Initializes a new stack and returns it
        stack_t NewStack()
        {
            stack_t *n_stack;
            n_stack=(stack_t*)malloc(sizeof(stack_t));
            n_stack->top_stack=NULL;
            return (*n_stack);  
        }

        // Returns 1 if the stack is empty, 0 otherwise
        int Empty(stack_t q)
        {
        if(q.top_stack==NULL)
            return 1;
        else 
            return 0;   
        }

        // Returns 1 if the stack is full, 0 otherwise
        int Full(stack_t q)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        // Pushes the element e in the stack. Returns 1 if it could Push.
        int Push(int e, stack_t *q)
        {       
            s_Node *nn;
            nn= (s_Node*)malloc(sizeof(s_Node));

            if(Full(*q))
            {
                printf("\n\t Stack is Full !! \n\n");
                return 0;   // return 0 if enstack NOT successful
            }
            else 
            { 
                nn->element=e;
                nn->next=q->top_stack;
                q->top_stack=nn;
                return 1;
            }
        }

        // Pops an element, placing it in e. Returns 1 if it could Pop.
        int Pop(int *e, stack_t *q)
        {   
            s_Node *temp;

            if(Empty(*q))  // Check if the stack is empty
            {
                    return 0;   // popping Failed
            }
            else
            {
            temp=q->top_stack;  // store the top in a temp ptr Node to free it after
            *e=q->top_stack->element; // Store the popped element in e
            q->top_stack=q->top_stack->next; // Point the top to the next element
            free(temp); // Free the popped Node
            return 1;
            }
        }

        void Printstack(const stack_t q)  
    {
            if(Empty(q))
                printf("\n\tStack is empty!!\n");
            else{
                s_Node *walker;
                walker = q.top_stack;   
                printf("\n\t This is the content of the stack:\n");
                  while(walker!=NULL)
                  {
                    printf("\t%d ",walker->element);
                    walker=walker->next;
                  }
          printf("\n");
        }
    }
    int  Peek (stack_t s)
    {   printf ("%d\n",s.top_stack->element);
        return s.top_stack->element; // Returning the top element of the stack
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `I think it crashes` - You *think* so? Have you traced it with a debugger, or with printfs?

Comment: Quick look, probably your `scanf`, you don't need the &.

Comment: No, it is not the 'scanf' because the file can be read correctly. I used also printf statments to come to this deduction. Thank you for your help

Comment: In Push, if the stack is full then you don't `free` nn. That won't cause the crash, but you will get a memory leak.

Comment: Your Peek function doesn't check for NULL. what happens when newInt is bigger than all of the elements in stack1?

Comment: I don't need to check for NULL inside Peek, because I am checking for it in the main.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're deferencing a `NULL` here:

```
int  Peek (stack_t s)
{   printf ("%d\n",s.top_stack->element);
```

During this sequence:

```
else 
{
    while ( newint > Peek (stack1) )
    {    //Repeat poping from stack1 and pushing into stack2
        // until it the integer read from the file is bigger than the top element of stack1
        printf ("gOT into THE WHILE LOOP\n");   
        Pop (&val1,&stack1);
        Push (val1, &stack2); 
        Printstack (stack2);            
    }
```

Because of your input list:

```
2  1  3
```

3 is larger than everything on your stack so you `pop` everything off while looking for an element larger than 3, that leaves your `stack1.top_stack` as `NULL`. Your check should be:

```
while (!Empty(stack1) && (newint > Peek (stack1)))
```

Comment: @user1680944 - you're welcome. A good debugger and being able to step throug the code is a very useful tool, can find these types of problems quickly!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
while ( newint > Peek (stack1) )
```

to

```
 while ( !Empty(stack1) && newint > Peek (stack1) )
```

Since your peek function doesn't handle Empty stacks, you have to check for it explicitly.